# Android: How do I perform automated integration tests with a server secured by OAuth

Tags: android, maven, continuous-integration, integration-testing, android-maven-plugin

I'm building an android application which fetches some data from a server which in turn controls access by OAuth. (Xing in my case, could be Facebook or whatever without loss of generality). Builds are controlled by Jenkins and the maven-android-plugin.

Proper integration testing of the application would require that I somehow pass the user credentials to the emulator under test. Assuming that I can put the credentials into the integration tester app at build time ([separate question about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585228/how-can-secret-api-keys-be-used-while-using-public-build-servers) on stack overflow), how would I go about simulating the user typing and clicking in the web browser which will be launched during the OAuth authorization phase?

Futher complicating the issue is that my own app (package com.mycompany.myapp) and the web brower used to enter the credentials (com.android.browser) share neither a common package not a signature, which seems to be required by Robotium ( see https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/QuestionsAndAnswers , question about test case spanning two applications)

Answer (score 2):

[Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/) can simulate user interaction like providing data to text inputs and so on and will be running as an instrumentation test on the devices.

The android-maven-plugin examples projects has some examples set up for using Robotium and can easily be used to execute these tests on all attached devices and emulators.

Comment: Robotium does not help in this case since I would need to span two applications. Question amended with this additional requirement.